# Private App not visible for Android users

Tags: android, apk, private

I have to make an app for an organization. The app must be visible only for the organization's users. I used Google Play Console to upload my apk and I did everything from this [tutorial](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en&authuser=1).

The problem is that even if I have added the app on Google Admin Console whitelist, an set the visibility to everyone, I can not see the app on my enrolled devices. The device is listed on mobile devices from Google Admin Device Management, I can see all the public apps from the app whitelist but not my private one.

On all the internet I couldn't find any helpful tutorial I have no idea where I did mistake.

Any help, tutorial or advice will be a new chance to find the problem in my configuration. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

After some checkings I found out that the apk had 0 supported devices because of one permission required in manifest file.

You may see how many supported devices has de apk in Release management -> Device catalog.

After removing that permission and uploading the new apk to Google Play Console, the app appeared.

Answer (score 1):

There is another work-around for your app to be used by some specific users. The play store allows an app to be in the beta mode where you can add the users of your app just by adding their Gmail addresses. This is mainly used for testing purpose, however, the application can be found in Google Play store from the account which you have added in the list of beta testers and it might serve your purpose.

For more information, please [follow this link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en).

Comment: solution is better of course, but if it's not a big organization you could just upload the apk to your cloud ad email it

Comment: What is main difference between beta testing and internal test?

Comment: They are almost the same thing actually.